# How to maintain a command from terminal running?

Tags: command-line, process

I launch connexion ssh to use rsync command in terminal and I would like to shutdown my computer, but I need to let run the process rsync.

I executed this command on a remote host. If I quit now then the process will stop I guess?

Yes I know I should run my command with option to avoid to lost the process.

Comment: how did you launch the command remotely? ssh?

Comment: What exact command? How was it executed - over SSH? Add details.

Comment: The typical way of managing this is to use screen(1).

Comment: @Sufiyan Ghori yes I use ssh then I use rsync

Comment: Look into using nohup, or screen, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

You can run `disown -a && exit` which will release all the shell processes you have started from the current shell and end the current shell. The processes will continue to run.

Answer (score 1):

It is very generic, and there are many solution.

You can use `nohup`. But often on remote host a `screen` (or `tmux`) is used.

On the first case: process continue also if terminal is terminated (but you should no more use stdin/stout/stderr (a redirect it is ok).

On the second, it is just a virtual terminal, so you can return (from an other computer) and see the terminal.

Comment: The command is running and I cant stop it now so there is a way to maintain the PID ?

Comment: Now it is late. I use the other tools, so I do not know.